How would you explain/translate "the ways of Yisrael Saba"?
How would you explain/translate "the ways of Yisrael Saba"?
Something like 'ancient traditional values or practices'?
Is there a source for this phrase?

How do you know this phrase exists?

Because I've heard many people use it.
